# Unable to convert String to byte

Tags: java, android, byte

I have following method in my project.

```
public byte[] getbytes(){
    byte[] b;
    b = str.getBytes();
    return new byte[]{
            (byte) 0,
            (byte) 1,
            (byte) 2,
            (byte) 5,
            (byte) b 
    };
}
```

The last byte contains string value. So I tried to get the bytes. But I am getting following error.

`error: incompatible types: byte[] cannot be converted to byte`.

Even though I am using `byte[]` instead of `Byte[]`.

According to my understanding :
**The Byte class wraps a value of primitive type byte in an object. An object of type Byte contains a single field whose type is byte**.

Getting confused here. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `b` is not a `byte`. It's a `byte[]`. An array.

Comment: the c;ass wrapper is irrelevant here, this is just wrong `(byte) b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others already said, byte[] is an array containing multiple bytes. There are 2 possibilies to return a byte array with the content of the String and some metadata:

1. You already know the String to have a length of 1:

> if (str.length == 1)

but if the String wouldn´t get longer than 1, you would use a char instead:

```
public byte[] getbytes(){
byte b;
b = (Byte) c; //c is a char
return new byte[]{
        (byte) 0,
        (byte) 1,
        (byte) 2,
        (byte) 5,
        (byte) b 
};
```

}

2. You dont know the length of the String:

   `````
       byte[] b;
       b = str.getBytes();
       byte[] output = new byte[b.length + 4];
       output[0] = 0;
       output[1] = 1;
       output[2] = 2;
       output[3] = 5;
       for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
       output[i + 4] = b[i];
       }
       return output;
   }````
   `````

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc tells you about that method:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

Thus that method returns an **array** of bytes: `byte[]`.

An array isn't a single value.  A box of eggs isn't an egg!

The real answer: don't assume from the **name** what a method is doing. Check out its exact signature `public byte[] getBytes​()` and read its javadoc.

I can't say more, as it is not clear what you actually intend to do here. As there is simply no "right" way to turn a sequence of bytes into a single byte.

If this is about having a byte array that contains all bytes, plus some header, it would go like this:

```
byte[] dataWithPrefix = new byte[b.length + 4];
dataWithPrefix[0] = (byte) 0;
dataWithPrefix[1] = (byte) 1;
...
```

to then use [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) to copy all bytes from b to that new array, at the position you want them to show up.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `byte[] b`. This means that `b` is a **byte array**. Later you cast it to a single `byte` using `(byte) b`. The JVM is complaining that you have asked it to turn an array of bytes (possibly containing thousands of bytes, since this is a compile time error) into a single byte.

If you know `b` will only contain one element, you can simply use `(byte) b[0]`.